# ksql - extract fields from a JSON String

Tags: json, apache-kafka, ksqldb

Have been trying to use ksqldb to extract fields from a JSON sting - since the data is a simple string, and it is not structured, unable to inspect it as we would do with a normal JSON object. How to get the following output by dynamically serialize the data?

Example:

**INPUT:**

```
{"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"_id\": {\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5a9427648b0beebeb6957cf8\"}, \"copyingData\": true}, \"operationType\": \"insert\", \"documentKey\": {\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5a9427648b0beebeb6957cf8\"}}, \"fullDocument\": {\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5a9427648b0beebeb6957cf8\"}, \"name\": \"Shae\", \"email\": \"sibel_kekilli@gameofthron.es\", \"movie_id\": {\"$oid\": \"573a1391f29313caabcd9637\"}, \"text\": \"Sapiente fugiat fugit quis omnis ipsum maiores. Est dolorem minima dicta labore facere. Sit vero vero quidem cumque sequi quibusdam dicta.\", \"date\": {\"$date\": 1410179981000}}, \"ns\": {\"db\": \"sample_mflix\", \"coll\": \"comments\"}}"}
```

Getting the above input in a Kafka topic using MongoDB Source Connector. Used JSON formatter and both key and value JSON convertor configuration in the source connector. However, the payload attribute in the above input is a JSON string.

I want to dynamically return the serialized format of the data.

**Expected OUTPUT:**

```
{"id":"5a9427648b0beebeb6957cf8", "name":"Shae", "email":"sibel_kekilli@gameofthron.es", "movie_id":"573a1391f29313caabcd9637", "date": 1410179981000}
```

Comment: You should set `value.converter.schemas.enabled=false` in the connector and try again

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer. 
Had been using the connector setting of `value.converter.schemas.enabled=false` but did not help and the values were still in string format. 
This helped and made me to look through the documentation again, found the following connector settings for string convertor which worked for me:

`key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter`